# Send a large message to a ServiceStack service

Tags: c#, web-services, servicestack

I need to create a service that will allow a client to send a message containing a large amount of data and I'm not sure how to structure the API.

Let's say a client wants to save a new object which contains a variable number of related objects. For instance, an Order, which contains several line items contained in OrderDetail objects. An Order may have over a 1000 OrderDetail objects related to it, each of which may contain 20-40KB of data. The client needs to know that the service has received the entire order.

I would like to explore using ServiceStack to create this. Creating a high traffic service is not something I'm very familiar with. We would typically use WCF, and it seems like people just recommend increasing the message size limit to accommodate a large message. I'm not sure if that's the best strategy with WCF, let alone ServiceStack.

Would it be better to send each OrderDetail as it's own message? I would be concerned about keeping the integrity of the entire Order going this route. Or should I just keep this as a single large message 20-40MB of data? Or should I try to stream it as a file?

Comment: Why not save the data in XML format or Serialize the Data and send the contents that way..?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying, this would be serialized. Some of the data is binary, but yes most of it could be XML. How does that change anything though? I would still have either a 40MB string of XML I'm sending, or I could stream it, or I could separate the XML into chunks to be reassembled on the server. My question still remains, which of these is the best option for sending a large amount of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ServiceStack's ProtoBuf support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Protobuf-format) - protocol buffers is the most efficient and compact wire format out there. Since it's simpler, try that first, before investigating the Streaming options in ServiceStack.

#### Streaming options in ServiceStack

If you've identified that your service will greatly benefit from Streaming, than here's an article on [sending a stream to ServiceStack](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501608/Sending-stream-to-ServiceStack) that shows how to Stream inside ServiceStack services. It shows how to use [IRequiresRequestStream](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#reading-directly-from-the-request-stream) which lets you stream the Request Body in your services:

Request DTO:

```
[Route("/upload/{FileName}", "POST")]
public class UploadPackage : IRequiresRequestStream
{
    public System.IO.Stream RequestStream { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Access to the Request Body Stream is injected into the `RequestStream` property of the Request DTO.