# ServiceStack uploading large files using chunks/buffer

Tags: file-upload, servicestack

I am running ServiceStack (v3) on a low-memory embedded device.

External clients can push large files to this device to store internally on the hard drive.

I followed the steps in [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501608/Sending-Stream-to-ServiceStack) CodePlex article, but the `Post()` method in ServiceStack only gets called when the file upload is completed. That leads me to believe that ServiceStack is buffering the entire file into memory.

I need the ability to handle a `System.IO.Stream` myself, and handle each chunk as it becomes available, so that I may immediately write the data to disk.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't state that you are using Mono, but I'm assuming that you will be, as you are running on an embedded device.  The problem you are encountering is caused by [`HttpRequest.Mono.cs`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/6ac538ead6cb9980f1d7d24a4c6fd601a06df177/src/ServiceStack/Host/HttpListener/ListenerRequest.Mono.cs#L77).  `multipart/form-data` (which is what most javascript file upload libraries use) is automatically pulled into memory streams by this class and is available through `Request.Files`.  Normally this is great, and makes uploading files super easy.  The problem comes when you want upload something large.

If you read the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15690513) StackOverflow response and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501608/Sending-stream-to-ServiceStack) CodeProject article you'll be instructed to take control of the DTO deserialization yourself using [`IRequiresRequestStream`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#reading-directly-from-the-request-stream)  So I whipped up a ServiceStack service and AngularJS client to test it out.  [Here is my first pass at the solution](https://gist.github.com/jlyonsmith/4bf5b5a1082e6e036466/09a38d34784304de4b43f5f9f0e3eaa69f9dc5c2).

Unfortunately, it does not work as expected.  The message parts are still deserialized to `Request.Files` as `MemoryStream`'s.  This is because `multipart/form-data` is still intercepted and handled low down the request processing chain in `HttpRequest.Mono`.

Further research indicates that `multipart/form-data` protocol useful for small files, but [as mythz himself points out](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/servicestack/IV4-fNvrrUk/0uWmfBuci8oJ) this was never really meant for uploading large amounts of data.  There are better ways to go about doing large file uploads...

My suggested solution to this problem is to use `IRequiresRequestStream` but stay away from `multipart/form-data` and just upload the binary data directly as the raw type (`Content-Type: image/jpeg`, for example.)  You'll have to do your own chunking and recombining of the file, but you'll have complete control of the process and you'll be all set to handle uploads of any size.  [Here is the final sample code](https://gist.github.com/jlyonsmith/4bf5b5a1082e6e036466).

Comment: As of NuGet ServiceStack 4.0.54, this is still true - the entire stream appears to be copied into a MemoryStream so the API's overall file-as-stream approach is broken for this part in Mono. I appear to have success using IRequiresRequestStream and changing the method to PUT as it seems to bypass the problematic MemoryStream usage found in LoadMultipart (Mono 4.x). YMMV.